# why are the PieChart labels cut off in LiveCharts2?

Tags: c#, wpf, pie-chart, livecharts

I use LiveCharts2 (beta.950) library to work with charts. I tried to create a PieChart with some values and labels outside it and I got this:
[image]
The PieChart is inside a border and as you can see - the labels are cut off. There are no margins or something like this in *xaml* code, only the PieChart control:

```xml
<lvc:PieChart Series="{Binding CartesianPieChartSeries}"></lvc:PieChart>
```

I fill up the chart like this (it is simplified version):

```cs
SKColor[] colors = new SKColor[] { SKColors.AntiqueWhite, SKColors.Crimson, SKColors.Maroon, SKColors.Aqua, SKColors.Silver };
var vals = new PieSeries<double>[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    var color = colors[i];
    vals[i] = new PieSeries<double>
    {
        Values = new double[] { i + 1 },
        InnerRadius = 120,
        Fill = new SolidColorPaint(color),

        DataLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Black),

        DataLabelsFormatter = point =>
        {
            var sv = point.StackedValue;
            var a = $"{(int)sv.Share:P0}";
            return a;
        },
        IsHoverable = false,
        AnimationsSpeed = null,
        DataLabelsPosition = LiveChartsCore.Measure.PolarLabelsPosition.Outer
    };
}
CartesianPieChartSeries = vals;
```

So there are two questions. Why do the labels cut off and why are the percentage labels all zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why are the percentage labels all zero?

Because you are casting to `int`. Try this:

```
DataLabelsFormatter = point =>
{
    var sv = point.StackedValue;
    var a = $"{sv.Share:P0}";
    return a;
}
```

As for the labels issue, I guess you could change the `DataLabelsPosition` property to another value or increase the margins around the chart.

Or use a negative `DataLabelsPadding`:

```
vals[i] = new PieSeries<double>
{
    ...
    DataLabelsPadding = new LiveChartsCore.Drawing.Padding(-5)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed percentage labels but still had the problem with the clips. I solved it by setting ```OuterRadiusOffset``` property and also used ```DataLabelsPadding ``` as in your answer but set to positive number.